# Xamarin-Forms | Android - Reference image in GroundOverlayOptions

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am using the `Android.gms.maps` class to create a custom renderer google map in my Xamarin Forms app, for android phones. I am looking to add an image to my map using `GroundOverlayOptions`

```
    GroundOverlayOptions newarkMap = new GroundOverlayOptions()
    .InvokeImage(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(/*My image?*/))
    .position(e.Point, 8600f, 6500f);
     map.AddGroundOverlay(newarkMap);
```

I need the images resource ID in the commented section of my code. How do I find out an images' resource ID? Is there an alternative way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Using `BitmapDescriptorFactory` you have multiple options available to how you obtain the `BitmapDescriptor`

- `FromResource`
- `FromAsset`
- `FromPath`
- `FromBitmap`

Couple of examples:

To use the `FromResource`, the image must be within your Resource tree, assumably within the `Drawable` subfolder, Xamarin will generate an id descriptor for you in the form of `Resource.Drawable.XXXXX` and that will be an integer constant:

```
var overlayOption = new GroundOverlayOptions()
    .InvokeImage(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.overlayface2))
    .Position(e.Point, 5000f, 5000f);
```

[image]

`FromAsset` loads the image from the "Assets" subfolder:

```
var overlayOption = new GroundOverlayOptions()
    .InvokeImage(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromAsset("OverlayFace.png"))
    .Position(e.Point, 5000f, 5000f);
```

[image]

`FromPath` loads the image from an arbitrary path, so you could load an image you downloaded and stored in the app's cache directory, or an image stored on an sdcard, etc...

```
var overlayOption3 = new GroundOverlayOptions()
    .InvokeImage(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromPath("/mnt/sdcard/Download/OverlayFace.png"))
    .Position(e.Point, 5000f, 5000f);
```

**Note:** The largest problem people run into is not setting the size of the image correctly, it is in **kilometers**.  not pixels, not miles, etc...

**Note:** Also for speed, keep your image sizes in the power of 2, otherwise the the map library will have to transform it into a power of 2 image everytime it loads the overlay (memory and performance hit)

Comment: You're a lifesaver today @SushiHangover !

Comment: @BarneyChambers no problem, I use `FromPath` a lot as my app downloads map overlays into the app's cache directory (airport info and KML based vector airport drawings, etc...)